# Use of var in the global namespace

Tags: javascript, global-variables, this

I'm reading "you don't know javascript" and I find some trouble with one example in the book "This & Object Prototypes".

When discussing the different rules for `this`, specifically in the "Implicit binding" paragraph, the author gives this example:

```
function foo() {
    console.log( this.a );
}

var obj = {
    a: 2,
    foo: foo
};

var bar = obj.foo; // function reference/alias!

var a = "oops, global"; // `a` also property on global object

bar(); // "oops, global"
```

However when trying this on JSFiddle I get an undefined output in console instead of the "oops, global".

Conversely, if I define `a` without `var` or using `window.a` I get the output intended by the author regardless of strict mode.

Why is this happening? Did something in ES6 change the way global variables should be declared?

Comment: I recommend using the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) to test JS code; it’s quicker and more reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default settings for JS Fiddle wrap the JS in a function and assign it as an *load* event handler.

Your tests are not in the global scope.

[image: JS Fiddle Default JS Configuration]